# Как в django получить записи у которых id не входит в множество?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Есть модель с вопросами и нужно получить записи у которых answer_id is null и id не равен ни одному значению из множества. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test_ids = Subject.objects.all()
result = Test.objects.filter(test_id__in=test_ids).filter(filter(test_id__isnull=False))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#in